# How to parse the nested json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am having the nested json where I want parse the worksheetData and display the list of worksheetdata in separate cards. I have tried used online [tool](https://app.quicktype.io/) parse but when I print the data it throws an error called "type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map"

**#Update**
Below is the home.dart file where I am getting the data error
Home.dart

```
class WorkSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const WorkSheet({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WorkSheetState createState() => new _WorkSheetState();
}

class _WorkSheetState extends State<WorkSheet> {

  Future<String> loadSheetDataFromAssets() async {
    return await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
        .loadString('assets/example.json');
  }

  Future loadSheetData() async {
    String jsonString = await loadSheetDataFromAssets();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    SheetData sheetData = new SheetData.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print('PName : ${sheetData.projectName}');
    print('Worksheet : ${sheetData.worksheetData}');
    print(sheetData);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadSheetData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Work sheet data'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: loadSheetData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.data == null){
            return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error));
          }else{
            return Card(child: Text(snapshot.data.toString()));
          }
        }
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code to print the data that gives error.

Comment: @camillo777 I have edited my code please look into it

Comment: First you provided a JSON for a list of SheetData but in the code you are loading only 1 SheetData; what you want to do?

Comment: I want to get the every worksheetdata array should be displayed in cards. I have provided in the above json.

Comment: Because the error states that "type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map'" so I think that you are trying to put a List of SheetData into a SheetData.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some external tools to generate your models like [quicktype](https://quicktype.io/)
Or any of the approaches described in the official documentation [doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class classes you want to convert fromJson are annotated with @JsonSerializable(). Please follow flutter documentation for this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

This with Autoatically convert all your nested classes that are declared with @JsonSerializable() but if you have to convert a list from Json, you have to write some extra code like this below

```
Map jsonObject = json.decode(jsonString);
          Iterable list = json.decode(jsonObject['worksheetData']);
          List<WorksheetData> datasheet = list.map((f) => WorksheetData.fromJson(f)).toList();
```

Comment: I am not getting how to do. Can you please see my updated code and help me.